# Spring cloud (Brixton RC2) eureka + feign or rest template configuration not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I'm using Spring Cloud Brixton RC2 for a simple demonstration. The components include a web app, gateway and eureka server (created using Spring Initializer).

The 2 instances of Gateway are registered with eureka server but I am not able to call the gateway using either Feign client or Rest template.

Configuration for Eureka Server (application.properties):

```
server.port=8771
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
eureka.server.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty=0
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=false
security.basic.enabled=true
security.user.name=discovery
security.user.password=pa$$word
```

Configuration for Gateway (application.properties and bootstrap.properties)

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://discovery:pa$$word@127.0.0.1:8771/eureka/

spring.application.name=Simple_Gateway
```

Configuration for Web App (application.properties and bootstrap.properties)

```
server.port=9090
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://discovery:pa$$word@localhost:8771/eureka/

spring.application.name=Simple_WebApp
```

[eureka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDYF7.png)

Configuration for bootstrap class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SimpleWebappApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleWebappApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("pwd").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/sign_in")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/restricted")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable();
    }

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @FeignClient("Simple_Gateway")
    interface GatewayClient {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/gateway/test")
        String getSessionId();
    }
```

When using the feign client, the following exception is thrown (stacktrace)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service id not legal hostname (Simple_Gateway)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.getName(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:215) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClient(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:174) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClients(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:161) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:86) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
```

The feign configuration is changed to `http://Simple_Gateway`, the following exception is thrown (stacktrace)

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: getSessionId failed and no fallback available.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:980) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224) ~[websocket-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:9.2.15.v20160210]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: getSessionId failed and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:805) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:789) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:99) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1494) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1384) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:313) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:305) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:100) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$3.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1005) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onError(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:71) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnRunHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1453) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$ExecutionHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1349) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:296) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:288) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$5.call(AbstractCommand.java:521) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$5.call(AbstractCommand.java:497) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar:1.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1350) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.cleanUrl(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:100) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:95) ~[feign-core-8.16.0.jar:8.16.0]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:74) ~[feign-core-8.16.0.jar:8.16.0]
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:80) ~[feign-hystrix-8.16.0.jar:8.16.0]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:293) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

When using the RestTemplate, the following exception is thrown (sorry about that.part of stacktrace shown. word count limit reached)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RC3.jar:1.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RC3.jar:1.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getInstance(SpringClientFactory.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getLoadBalancer(SpringClientFactory.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.getLoadBalancer(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RC2.jar:1.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.1.0.RC3.jar:1.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Am I missing any configuration or configured it incorrectly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use feign and rest template, even though `Simple_WebApp` is not a hostname, it must follow real hostname rules and underscore `_` isn't a valid character in a hostname.

Underscores are not valid in URIs as per [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

This issue is also addressed in several github issues in Spring Cloud:

- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/263
- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1582

Spring cloud has more robust and descriptive error messaging around this issue in 1.2.0.M1 and above.  Enhancement here:  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/159

Comment: Thanks a million. I overlooked that bit in the configuration. Works well :)